# built-in testing for stationarity in matlab

Tags: matlab

This seems like a fairly common test to have to use, but I cannot find any built-in tools in matlab that help me find out whether a given time series is stationary. Everything I have found so far is in the Econometrics toolkit, which I don't have. If there is nothing built-in, could someone please recommend the best/easiest test for stationarity that I could write on my own? 
Thank you,
Paul

edit
I was able to perform the cumsum test using the following code:

```
len = length(array);
arraySquared = array.*array
kVector = cumsum(arraySquared);
nSquared = sum(arraySquared);
DScore = max(abs(kVector./nSquared - kVector/len))`
```

But I am still not sure how to interpret this statistic. In the literature it just says to reject the null hypothesis that the series is stationary when the D-statistic is "high", but it doesn't give a standard cdf for D that I can use to measure confidence, like a Z-score for a normal distribution. I am getting values ranging from 3 to 18 for most of my time series (which are based on a volatile period of S&P500 data).

Comment: I'm not sure, and I suggest you to do more investigation, but from wikipedia article it seems that cusum has a normal cdf. So, by the table, I see the the probability of your test value to be lower than 2.9 is 0.9981, so there's a 0.0019 chance that an higher value comes from the same distribuiton. The same goes for 18, the probability still gets lower. As in every statistical based test, you have to define your first type error probability. Again, I suggest you to do further investigation, because I'm not a statistics specialist

Comment: thank you--I can do a lot knowing that the cumsum statistic has a normal cdf.

Comment: although looking at the wikipedia article, I am not sure where you got that.

Comment: There's a table, just look under process observations -> underlying distribution you can find a proof here: http://epub.wu.ac.at/1778/1/document.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classic statistical test for stationarity of a time series goes under the name of CUSUM

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSUM

(very old but still actual material)

A relatively new, but harder to implement technique is known as ICI (intersection of intervals of confidence), I've used it while at school more than a year ago. You can find related papers with this google search:

https://www.google.it/search?q=ICI+rule&oq=ICI+rule&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1754j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=intersection+of+confidence+intervals&safe=off

The easiest algorithm consists in get a slice of your time series (e.g. the first 100 samples), estimate mean and variance in order to be able to fix an upper and lower threshold with known confidence. Then, you can say that the time series is stationary if it lies between your boundaries. Obviously, this technique introduces a probability of false negatives (when the entity of the change is so small that it lies between the boundaries)

CUSUM is based on the idea of doing a "running average" of the values of the time series, but with the additional advantage of  shortening the detection delay (another known issue when dealing with running averages and sliding windows)

Comment: ahah, thank you. The cumsum test seems to be the most straightforward of all test I have seen so far.